# Sharing of a junction object

Tags: security, sharing, sharing-rule

What access would a junction object have if one master object has read-write access while the other master object has read access through the sharing rules with organization-wide defaults private for both master objects?

Comment: If I am not wrong, there is the primary relationship and this relationship is responsible by the sharing level.

Comment: Yes, I think it is defined by the Primary relationship of Master-Detail Relationship on junction object. The first relationship you create, that's the Primary, the second one is Secondary. More details here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212396&language=en_US&type=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Junction Object (Child) will inherit sharing settings from it's primary Master, the one which was associated first to it.

Answer (score 2):

The right answer is **least permissive will win**

Lets say **Object A** is a Junction between **B** and **C**

If the User have **Public RW** on B and **No Access** on C

Access on Object A will be No Access

Comment: can you confirm this with documentation